# Ajax Form Submit using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, api

I am working with a form that I want to submit with ajax to a api that sends email to the email mentioned in it and the api was working in postman with raw data but I can't get it to work with the form using jQuery and ajax so if you guys can tell me why my function is not working and sending the email it will be of great help to me

Function for form submit:-

```
 $(function() {

  $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
      // get values from FORM
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
      // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
      if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
      }
      $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
      $.ajax({
    "url": "http://178.18.243.33:8089/email/sendmailusingtemplate",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({
        "to": "nkulhari96@gmail.com",
        "cc": "services@gmail.com",
        "template": "contact_us_001",
        "name": "name",
        "email": "email",
        "mobile": "phone",
        "message": "message"
    }),
    },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          // Success message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
          // Fail message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    },
    filter: function() {
      return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
  $('#success').html('');
});
```

Code for Form:-

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="">
                            <div class="control-group form-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" id="name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group form-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" id="phone" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <div class="help-block"></div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group form-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" id="email" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <div class="help-block"></div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group form-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea rows="5" cols="100" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" id="message" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block"></div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send Message</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Q: Is the URL you're posting to capable of sending an e-mail?  Have you actually tested that URL (e.g. with Postman)?  Q: Are there any error messages (e.g. in the server logs)?

Comment: the url is correct and working with postman but my function for form is not submitting the form and not sending the email

Comment: OK - this is definitely a job for Chrome Developer Tools: 1) Modify your code.  Clean up the indentation.  Add `debug` breakpoints at points you believe are getting executed.  Add as many `console.log()` statements as makes sense. 2) Bring up your web page (and JS) in Chrome.  3) Check for any JS syntax errors.  4) Hit F12 to display dev tools.  5) Try "sending an e-mail" and trace through your JS code execution in dev tools: [source] and [console] tabs. 6) Look at the [network] tab, too.